# Search users by more than just username

Tags: support, user-accounts, search

I need to search AU users by more than just username - actually by location, bio or website. Is this possible? In the users tab search only works by username only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can search by a few extra terms. If you desperately need to find a person —and have a good reason— bug one of us and we'll try to help you.

Additionally the public data is accessible through [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/new). You can compose a SQL query to search from a number of fields, including location, bio and website. Here's a simple search on the bio field which finds my user:

```
SELECT * from Users where AboutMe like '%thepcspy%'
```

Note that the data.SE engine works on a *slightly* old database. I don't know what the delay is these days but it isn't current. It should be good enough for most purposes though.

You can also download the [SE Data Dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and do things manually... Though they are 25GB  compressed.

Comment: Thanks man. Just wanted to find the Kenyans in here and invite them to an Ubuntu Kenya Meet-Up organized by my friend (the guy who introduced me to Ubuntu) and I. Is that a good enough reason?

Comment: I don't think we can search by country (just names, email, etc). You'd be best off with data.stackexchange: `SELECT * from Users where AboutMe like '%kenya%' or Location like '%kenya%'`

Comment: The query works but I don't appear on the list - weird...

Comment: also found this for Moroccan users - http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/292699/top-20-stackoverflow-moroccan-users

Comment: Yeah wrapping the field in `LOWER()` did the trick: `SELECT * from Users where LOWER(AboutMe) like '%kenya%' or LOWER(Location) like '%kenya%'` finds 132 rows.